# How does one overwrite a rb_ function in a ruby c extension?

Tags: c, ruby, ruby-c-extension

I am having trouble figuring out how to override a rb_ function (like rb_ivar_get) in c.
I have the following code:

```
#include "ruby.h"

void Init_metaobject();
VALUE meta_cObject = Qnil;
VALUE meta_ivar_get(VALUE obj, VALUE mId, VALUE mWarn);
VALUE meta_ivar_set(VALUE obj, VALUE mId, VALUE val);

void Init_metaobject() {
    meta_cObject = rb_define_class("MetaObject", rb_cObject);
    rb_define_method(meta_cObject, "meta_ivar_get", meta_ivar_get, 2);
    rb_define_method(meta_cObject, "meta_ivar_set", meta_ivar_set, 2);
}

VALUE
rb_ivar_get(obj, id)
    VALUE obj;
    ID id;
{
    return meta_ivar_get(obj, ID2SYM(id), Qtrue);
}

VALUE
rb_attr_get(obj, id)
    VALUE obj;
    ID id;
{
    return meta_ivar_get(obj, ID2SYM(id), Qfalse);
}

VALUE
rb_ivar_set(obj, id, val)
    VALUE obj;
    ID id;
    VALUE val;
{
    return meta_ivar_set(obj, ID2SYM(id), val);
}

VALUE
meta_ivar_get(obj, mId, mWarn)
    VALUE obj;
    VALUE mId;
    VALUE mWarn;
{
    VALUE val;
    ID id = rb_to_id(id);
    int warn = RTEST(warn);

    switch (TYPE(obj)) {
      case T_OBJECT:
      case T_CLASS:
      case T_MODULE:
    if (ROBJECT(obj)->iv_tbl && st_lookup(ROBJECT(obj)->iv_tbl, id, &val))
        return val;
    break;
      default:
    if (FL_TEST(obj, FL_EXIVAR) || rb_special_const_p(obj))
        return generic_ivar_get(obj, id, warn);
    break;
    }
    if (warn) {
    rb_warning("instance variable %s not initialized", rb_id2name(id));
    }
    return Qnil;
}

VALUE
meta_ivar_set(obj, mId, val)
    VALUE obj;
    VALUE mId;
    VALUE val;
{
    ID id = rb_to_id(mId);  
    if (!OBJ_TAINTED(obj) && rb_safe_level() >= 4)
    rb_raise(rb_eSecurityError, "Insecure: can't modify instance variable");
    if (OBJ_FROZEN(obj)) rb_error_frozen("object");
    switch (TYPE(obj)) {
      case T_OBJECT:
      case T_CLASS:
      case T_MODULE:
    if (!ROBJECT(obj)->iv_tbl) ROBJECT(obj)->iv_tbl = st_init_numtable();
    st_insert(ROBJECT(obj)->iv_tbl, id, val);
    break;
      default:
    generic_ivar_set(obj, id, val);
    break;
    }
    return val;
}
```

And the following test:

```
require 'metaobject'

class Tracker < MetaObject

  attr_accessor :ivar

  def initialize
    @ivar = nil
  end

  def meta_ivar_get(symbol, warn)
    puts "Instance variable, #{symbol}, retrieved"
    super(symbol, warn)
  end

  def meta_ivar_set(symbol, obj)
    puts "Instance variable, #{symbol}, changed to #{obj.inspect}"
    super(symbol, obj)
  end

end

obj = Tracker.new
obj.ivar = "Modified"
puts obj.ivar
```

The output of which is only:

```
Modified
```

My thoughts are that the ruby linker is veiling my definition of rb_ivar_get, rb_attr_get, and rb_ivar_set with its definition found in variables.c. Am I right? If so, how can I change it some that that my methods veil ruby's and not the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with an extra .so file. The only way to edit an internal Ruby function is changing it directly. Go to `variable.c`, edit it and recompile the whole interpreter. You can, instead, overwrite the `attr_accessor`.

**EDIT**

Another solution with `set_trace_func`. This is very slow and I don't thick this is the right way to do it. Anyway, here is it:

```
$instance_variables_table = {}
$instance_variable_created_proc = proc do |var, value|
  puts "Instance variable #{var} created with #{value.inspect}."
end
$instance_variable_changed_proc = proc do |var, new, old|
  puts "Instance variable #{var} changed from #{old.inspect} to #{new.inspect}."
end

set_trace_func(proc {|type, file, line, func, binding, mod|
  unless type == "call"
    eval("instance_variables", binding).each do |iv|
      value = eval("instance_variable_get(:#{iv})", binding)
      if $instance_variables_table.has_key? iv
        if $instance_variables_table[iv] != value
          new = value
          old = $instance_variables_table[iv]
          $instance_variable_changed_proc[iv, new, old]
        end
      else
        $instance_variable_created_proc[iv, value]
      end
    end
  end
  $instance_variables_table = {}
  eval("instance_variables", binding).each do |iv|
    $instance_variables_table[iv] = eval("instance_variable_get(:#{iv})", binding)
  end
})
```

Test code:

```
class A
  def initialize
    @test = 1
    @test = 2
  end
  def a
    @test = 3
  end
end
A.new.a
```

Output:

```
Instance variable @test created with 1.
Instance variable @test changed from 1 to 2.
Instance variable @test changed from 2 to 3.
```

I'm not sure if it works in all cases or if it can be simplified. If you want to do it in a real application, edit `variable.c`.

Comment: I can't overwrite `attr_accessor`, because, for me, the main point of adding this extension was to be able to track modifications directly to the `@ivar = "some value"` calls. So you're saying in order to do that I will have to edit and recompile the source, there is no other way?

Comment: Thank you very much! That should work perfectly for my purposes.